# How to use sed or awk properly in sql dump file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, mysql

There is a sql dump file that i need to modify regarding the pattern that it shows up.
The pattern is like the following:

> /*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */ 
>   
>  / *!50013 DEFINER='test'@'%' SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
>   
>  / *!50001 VIEW 'SOME DATA' AS select 'SOME DATA'.'SOME DATA' AS 'SOME DATA','SOME DATA'.'SOME DATA' AS 'SOME DATA'...
>   / *!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */; 
>   / *!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */; 
>   / *!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */; 
>   / *!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

And every pattern, i would like to modify it like this using `sed` or `awk` or both:

> /*!50001 CREATE VIEW 'SOME DATA' AS select 'SOME DATA'.'SOME DATA' AS 'SOME DATA','SOME DATA'.'SOME DATA' AS 'SOME DATA','SOME DATA'....
>   
> / *!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */; 
>   / *!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */; 
>   / *!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */; 
>   / *!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

To sum up, i would like to erase everything between CREATE and VIEW. I tried the following commands but it didn't work:

```
sed 's/50001 CREATE.*VIEW//' dumpsqlfile.sql
sed "/50001 CREATE/,/VIEW/d" dumpsqlfile.sql
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format your sample input/output in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If `CREATE` is in the line, remove everything after it and save the resulting line in `saved`.
- If `saved` is empty, print the current line
- If `saved` is set and this line contains `VIEW`, remove everything before `VIEW`, print the previously `saved` line followed by the current modified line and make `saved` empty again.

```
/CREATE/{sub(/CREATE.*/,"CREATE");saved=$0}
!saved
saved&&/VIEW/{
        sub(/.*VIEW/,"VIEW")
        print saved " " $0
        saved=""
}
```

Save it as a `script.awk` and run it with `awk -f script.awk dumpsqlfile.sql`. The output:

```
/*!50001 CREATE VIEW 'SOME DATA' AS select 'SOME DATA'.'SOME DATA' AS 'SOME DATA','SOME DATA'.'SOME DATA' AS 'SOME DATA'...
/ *!50001 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/ *!50001 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */;
/ *!50001 SET collation_connection = @saved_col_connection */;
/ *!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
```

---

---

```
sed 's/50001 CREATE.*VIEW//' dumpsqlfile.sql
```

**does not work** because sed is a line oriented tool. It will stop looking for a pattern once it reaches a newline character. And

```
sed "/50001 CREATE/,/VIEW/d" dumpsqlfile.sql
```

also **does not work** because it starts deleting every line between a line matching `50001 CREATE` until a line matching `VIEW`, including the boundary lines.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work either,  the file remained the same.

Comment: @IoannisPantelidis The file is not supposed to change, the output you get should be the desired. If you redirect it to a file, e.g. `awk -f script.awk dumpsqlfile.sql > newdump.sql`, you should notice that the changes were applied in the new file. **Do not** fall into the trap of redirecting to the same file, that would leave you with nothing D:

Comment: It seems that preferable pattern was created but i observed that the CREATE TABLE queries are vanished.

Comment: @IoannisPantelidis Please [edit] the question to update your sample file. That indicates there is a `CREATE` that is not paired with a following `VIEW`.